# OpenTripPlanner API Elevation values unclear

Tags: java, api, xml, rest, opentripplanner

I'm using the OpenTripPlanner  [Planner API](http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.0.0/resource_PlannerResource.html) to find directions.

The API returns XML with the geometry of the line (2D) and the elevation data separately, for example

The 2D line geometry is as [encodedPolylineBean](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?csw=1) in:

```
response
.plan
..intineraries
...legs
....legGeometry
.....points
```

And looks something like

```
wnseIhqzL??DCl@m@b@m@lA}AjB}B`@g@d@q@\\i@l@y@Vc@vAqCbAeCvAsDx@qBdCaG^{@DGr@_AxFiAjDcAv@]jAg@h@WlBcA\\Sz@c@@RPxA@`@Ad@Ex@@NDJBJ^dATp@h@xCBN^x@h@jAX^`AhApAzAbAfAfAhAtAxA|AfArBl@|Ad@vAXxCrAt@X^Vn@`@pA`ApA`AvAdAzAd@\\Ep@KFAbDgAhBwBnBkCBE`@i@p@_@t@a@zAa@VGzAw@x@jCn@pBFPNf@j@dBvAxDHTXz@lAfDvA|D?D`BfFz@hCFPz@nCdA~CQb@
```

But the elevation data is in:

```
response
.plan
..intineraries
...leg
....steps
.....elevation
```

And Looks like:

```
<elevation>
  <first>5.322</first>
  <second>73.87</second>
</elevation>
<elevation>
  <first>15.322</first>
  <second>74.25</second>
</elevation>
<elevation>
  <first>25.322</first>
  <second>74.56</second>
</elevation>
<elevation>
```

What I don't understand is:

1. What is the difference between the `<first>` and `<second>` elevation?
2. Why when the PolylineBean line is decoded does it have fewer points than the number of values given for the elevation?

For reference, a full XML response is available [here](https://github.com/mem48/opentripplanner-malcolm/blob/master/plan.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found out that the answer is:

First - is the distance along the leg (i.e. it resets to 0 after each leg)

Second - is the elevation

The elevation points don't correspond directly to points on the PolylineBean but can be interpolated by calculating the length along the line.

Comment: Dear @falcs, I am also interested in the elevation data model. Where can I find relative information?

Comment: There is not much documentation, I had to work it out. There is some at http://dev.opentripplanner.org/javadoc/1.3.0/org/opentripplanner/routing/core/RoutingRequest.html